# Solving the Diophantine Equation $Axy^2 + Bxz^2 + Cy + Dz = 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

While working on a problem, I obtained the system

$$
\begin{align}
ub_3+a_4 t=1\\
ut(2p^2+q^2 )-a_4 b_3=r
\end{align} \tag{1}
$$

where $p,q,r$ are fixed constants and $u, b_3, a_4, t$ are unknown integers.

I tried eliminating a term by multiplying the equations by $t(2p^2 + q^2)$ and $b_3$ respectively

$$
\begin{align}
utb_3 (2p^2+q^2 )+a_4 t^2 (2p^2+q^2 )=t(2p^2+q^2 ) \\
utb_3 (2p^2+q^2 )-a_4 b_3^2=rb_3
\end{align} \tag{2}
$$

and subtracted to obtain

$$
a_4 t^2 (2p^2+q^2 )+a_4 b_3^2=t(2p^2+q^2 )-rb_3 \tag{3}
$$

This is a diophantine equation of the form

$$
Axy^2 + Bxz^2 + Cy + Dz = 0 \tag{4}
$$

**Are there any methods for solving this type of equation? Please provide references to solution methods.**

---

In general, I am looking for methods to solve the system

$$
\begin{align}
Awx + Byz = C\\
Dwz + Exy = F
\end{align} \tag{5}
$$

which was reduced to the form in Eqn. $(4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{cases}
ub_3+a_4 t=1\\
ut(2p^2+q^2)-a_4 b_3=r
\end{cases} \\ \overset{\displaystyle\not{t}}{\implies} \bigg(2a_4 b_3+r\bigg)^2+(2p^2+q^2)\bigg(2b_3u-1\bigg)^2 = (2p^2+q^2)+r^2$

it is "quadratic Thue".

And like

$Axy^2 + Bxz^2 + Cy + Dz = 0 \implies A (2 B x z + D)^2 + B (2 A x y + C)^2 = A D^2 + B C^2$

Answer (score 1):

►Your initial system has the form (we can change $-$  by $+$)$$xy+zw=1\\axw+zy=b$$   Four unknowns and only two equations so there are many solutions (maybe not integers). Taking $(y,w)$ fixed coprimes, for example $(4,5)$ the first equation has infinitely many integer solutions and you have to test if  some of them are compatible with the second equation. This suggest a way to find out solutions perhaps.

►► Your general system $(5)$ leads, by elimination of one unknown, to an equation of the form $(4)$. You do have, by elimination of $w$
$$\begin{align}
Awx + Byz = C\\
Dwz + Exy = F
\end{align}\Rightarrow AEyx^2-DByz^2=AFx-DCz$$ and the same happens if you eliminate any other unknown: you get an equation like $(4)$.

►►►Let the equation $$Axy^2 + Bxz^2 + Cy + Dz = 0 \tag{4}$$
It is a cubic and find its integer solutions could be very hard or impossible, even when there exists integers solutions.

Comment: Yes. My current approach is to take $(u,t) = (\alpha, \beta)$ to get $$\alpha b_3 + \beta a_4 = 1\\b_3a_4 = \alpha \beta (2p^2 + q^2) - r$$ and then complete the squares to get a Pell-type equation. But then, we have to try different $\alpha, \beta$ values. We need $1 - 4(\alpha \beta (2p^2 + q^2) - r) = \delta^2$ for some $\delta \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

$Axy^2+Bxz^2+Cy+Dz=0 \iff x(Ay^2+Bz^2)=-Cy-Dz $

In your situation, $A \geq 0$ and $B=1$, so you only have $Ay^2+Bz^2=0$ in a few specific cases you should be able to sort out. Outside of those cases: $x=\frac {-Cy-Dz}{Ay^2+Bz^2}$ and you can check that this yields all the solutions.

From that you have to find $y$ and $z$ so that $Ay^2+Bz^2$ divides $Cy+Dz$, but as far as I know there is no streamlined way to solve that.